Prune leaning avocado tree?
I have this leaning avocado tree from a home we bought two years ago and am thinking it would be good to prune a section of the tree so its center of gravity is more balanced closer to the trunk. Is this a good idea? I'll include some images of the tree and the areas I'm thinking to prune. If it is good to prune I'm not sure how far back I should prune and could use guidance there.

Here is the area I'm thinking to prune, though this area does bear quite a bit of fruit but I'm thinking it is better that the tree is balanced.

A view from the west side with different options on how much to prune with A being the largest.

This is a top down view to show much much the trunk is leaning the previous owners added these brace supports. On the side opposite from the direction the tree is leaning some of the roots are starting to become exposed, I don't know how long ago this started.

The pictures posted here are of a single avocado tree.
Appreciate any advise this community is willing to share.

I see your concern. The tree appears to be very unbalanced, which is likely why the supports were added. Ideally, training the tree would have happened earlier in it's lifetime and you wouldn't have such an unbalanced tree now. However, it's not too late to train it and help it be more balanced and self-supporting.
When deciding how to prune an Avocado tree, there's a few basics that are good to keep in mind.
From californiaavocadogrowers.com:


Make major cuts clean, and in line, with the trunk contour
When renovating a grove, aim to remove large, interfering — and low-lying laterals, badly crossed limbs and spilt crotches
Pruning needs to balance the side‐shoot growth and remove strong, upright water shoots, in order to achieve a good central-leader shape
A conical, or pyramidal, tree shape enables good light interception and minimizes unproductive bare areas


Also, from the University of California Agriculture and Natural Resources:

Major or heavy pruning should only be done in the early part of the year—January, February, March and April. [...] if heavy pruning is needed, I suggest you remove one major branch at a time.

Looking at your pictures and taking into consideration the recommendation from the resources I posted above, I would suggest pruning the larger area (i.e. label "A" in your image), or possibly even more. An avocado tree should be fine if you trim one or two major branches back to the trunk once per year. This is known as renewal pruning (read more about it here). Avocado trees usually only fruit on new wood, so renewal pruning becomes necessary to prevent the fruit from only growing on the extremities of the tree.

"Heavy pruning should only be done in the early part of the year." Is this rule fixed, or just opinion?

Probably worth clarifying that the pictures I've posted so far are of a single large avocado tree, there does happen to be a dwarf tree but it does not appear in the photos. Unfortunate but the vines and trees near the fence make the outline of the avocado a little hard to differentiate. Thank you for your informative response.

@YosefBaskin "Heavy pruning should only be done in the early part of the year." — This isn't a rule but rather a recommendation. If you can wait until after a harvest or before fruit starts growing for the year, then it will cause less stress on the tree. It's possible to prune during the growing season, but I would only do it if the need was dire (branches are at risk of breaking or are diseased) since it puts the tree at higher risk.
Here's an article that corroborates my advice for when summer pruning might be appropriate.

The issue I see us that the trees are too close to each other. Its natural for some trees to be crooked. But in this case the larger tree is going to affect the smaller trees.
You may need to prune the larger one to provide space for the smaller one to grow into. You can prune the smaller one to make it balanced.  Or you can treat the whole group as one. And not worry about it too much.
